# Global attribute in Woocommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

Following up my question in this thread [Display Woocommerce product attribute on archive page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63527081/display-woocommerce-product-attribute-on-archive-page) , I would like to also display  my attribute on the cart page and checkout page just below each product name in the tables.

I have this code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'product_descrition_to_cart_items', 20, 2 );

function product_descrition_to_cart_items( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ){
    $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $taxonomy = 'pa_delivery';
    $value = $product->get_attribute($taxonomy);
    if ($product->get_attribute($taxonomy)) {
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => get_taxonomy($taxonomy)->labels->singular_name,
            'value' => $product->get_attribute($taxonomy),
        );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

But how to combine all functions in order to optimize code?

Answer (score 0):

After the line

```
$value = $product->get_attribute($taxonomy);
```

You never use the result of `$value`

If you did, your code could be simplified code down to:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'product_descrition_to_cart_items', 20, 2 );
function product_descrition_to_cart_items( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ){
    $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $taxonomy = 'pa_delivery';
    $value = $product->get_attribute($taxonomy);
    if ($value) {
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => get_taxonomy($taxonomy)->labels->singular_name,
            'value' => $value,
        );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Although WooCommerce does cache data whenever it retrieves it from the database, so if you're worried about multiple function calls slowing down the website, you don't need to be worried about that. You just need to be worried about creating easy to maintain code.

Comment: There is no way to combine the function with my previous functions(see link I mentioned)?

Comment: The question to ask yourself is what logic are all of the functions doing that's that same that you want to extract out into a separate function? There isn't anything that I can see.

Comment: I don't want to extract anything - I simply need to display my attribute on single product page, product archives, cart, checkout and emails!